# LibreOffice changes my formula to " ¿ "

Tags: libreoffice

LibreOffice changes my formula to "¿" character. I have a file.docx and when I open file on LibreOffice, it puts "¿" instead of my formula. But when I double click on formula, it shows correctly under page.

[image]

How do I show the formula correctly; can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double quotes `""` to show the text within formula.

Your formula should look like this:

```
Sat = {1-3[ min {left ("Red.Green.Blue" right)} ]} over {("Red+Green+Blue")} newline
Sat = "Red-Green"
```

Each "¿" character is now replaced by the correct text in the formula: Red, Green, Blue. The formula after the newline is assumed to have uppercase letters.